# Use same PHP encrypt method as in Java

Tags: javascript, java, php, encryption, base64

I've made this PHP encrypt script. Now I was wondering how this could be done in Java. I was considering giving this up, and coding it in Javascript so it could be used in both languages. This is unfortunately not what I want. How can I do so in Java?

```
<?php
  $encrypted = encrypt("Hello goodbye", "Pizza");
  $decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, "Pizza");

  echo $encrypted;
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $decrypted;

  function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $result = '';
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
      $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
      $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
      $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
      $result.=$char;
    }

    return base64_encode($result);
  }

  function decrypt($string, $key) {
    $result = '';
    $string = base64_decode($string);

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
      $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
      $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
      $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
      $result.=$char;
    }

    return $result;
  }
?>
```

I am not asking to write some code for me (but it would be great), but I would like to be helped or get a push in the right direction

**EDIT:**
**I do not want to post and get to the PHP file via Java**

Comment: you can check this out if it helps : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: This is not even encryption, just implementing some scrambling in Java. As this is not a code service, please post the java code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I don't even have the Java code, as I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: In such case, the best course of actions is deleting this question and looking for help on some Java forum. Once you have the code you are welcome to ask a new question here, granted it satisfy the on topic guidelines ([help/on-topic])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This GitHub repository solved it: [Android PHP Encrypt Decrypt](https://github.com/serpro/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AdvanceEncryptionSecurity {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 2;
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'P', 'R', 'S', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'A', 'P', 'F', 'A', 'A', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'e', 'd' };
    private static String salt = "prs and pfa";

    public static String encrypt(String value) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);  
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        String valueToEnc = null;
        String eValue = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            valueToEnc = salt + eValue;
            byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
            eValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
        }
        return eValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String value) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        String dValue = null;
        String valueToDecrypt = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(valueToDecrypt);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            dValue = new String(decValue).substring(salt.length());
            valueToDecrypt = dValue;
        }
        return dValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
        return key;
    }
}
```

Try this code. It can `encrypt` and `decrypt`. I'm assuming you know how to code in java.

Comment: I am using it on android java so it can't import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder and encoder

Comment: I solved the import error. How can I provide a key myself or something like that? Because  I'm not receiving the same encrypted phrase as when I'm encrypting it with PHP

Comment: We have different  algo that's why we don't have the same encrypted phrase.