# Symfony - How to secure API Controller? What else can I do?

Tags: php, api, authentication, symfony, security

Hi I am creating a react native app for a company, the app is for payroll information. They have a symfony website already made. I want to be able to connect to the live api and in turn the database. I ask the current employee in charge of the server to delete the line of code(**bold) that checks the IP address of the user. He is weary of exposing sensitive databases to the internet.

The API code is down below. Is there anything I can do to beef up security? Or another approach I am not thinking about?

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $username = $request->request->get('UserVar');
    $password = $request->request->get('PassVar');
    $key = $request->request->get('KeyVar');

    if (isset($username) and isset($password) **and ( in_array($this->getParameter('portal_ip'), explode(',', getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))))** and $key == 'THISISTHEKEYHARDCODED') {

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $RAW_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM employee where md5(username) = :username and md5(password) = :password and useraccess = 1 ;';

      $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);

      $statement->bindValue('username', $username);
      $statement->bindValue('password', $password);
      $statement->execute();

      $result = $statement->fetchAll();
      if (count($result) == 1) {
        $location = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App\Entity\Location')->find($result[0]['location'])->getLocName();
        $log = new Log();
        $log->setUSER(0);
        $log->setENT('employee');
        $log->setENTID($result[0]['id']);
        $log->setACT('LOGIN');
        $log->setMESSAGE(serialize(array('Employee has logged into portal')));
        $log->setACTDATE(new \DateTime);
        $log->setIP(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'));
        $em->persist($log);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array('success', 'THISISRANDOMSTRINGOFNUMBERS', $result[0]['id'], $result[0]['firstname'] . ' ' . $result[0]['lastname'], md5($result[0]['password']), $location, $result[0]['location']));
      } else {

        return new JsonResponse(array('error', 'THISISRANDOMSTRINGOFNUMBERS'));
      }
    } else {
      return new JsonResponse(array('nope'));
      //throw new NotFoundHttpException('Sorry not existing!');
    }
  }
```

I am new to this I am a co-op student.

Comment: I'm not sure that you persuade your boss to change this method because restrict connection to one IP is probably the most secure method and - obviously - not comfortable to work with it. This is an often practice when we are working with not modern code (and this code looks like simple solution). You can try suggest to use autorization based on some token (which is the most popular solution).

Comment: @OliwerLisek I am weary about adding a token and making changes to the database. Would an encryption of data be enough??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736945/use-same-php-encrypt-method-as-in-java